# MAX function in t-sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get max column value across a few tables. For instance in the below snippet (it does not work) i am trying
to get MAX value from a column name 'tickvalue' which is in all 3 tables A, B and C. Not sure how to get the value.

Data type of tickvalue column is timestamp.

```
select 
c.somkey
,MAX(a.tickvalue, b.tickvalue, c.tickvalue) as tickvalue
from A as a
join B as b
on a.key = b.key
join C as c
on b.somekey = c.somkey
where a.key = '<some key>'
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to get in the first column of the resulting recordset? But it looks like you already know that it will be an empty string.

Comment: @Igor update the code snippet

Comment: how does "it does not work" manifest itself?

Comment: @Igor I just wanted to convey my intent through the snippet. The snippet does not work.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how the `MAX()` aggregate function works in TSQL (see here: [TSQL MAX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx))
The MAX function gets the maximum value in a single column only.

To achieve what you want here, you'll have to get the three values into a single column. This can be done using `UNPIVOT` [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This snippet might help you out.

```
CREATE TABLE #A (ID INT, tickvalue INT)
CREATE TABLE #B (ID INT, tickvalue INT)
CREATE TABLE #C (ID INT, tickvalue INT)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (2,4)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (3,7)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (4,2)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (5,8)

INSERT INTO #B VALUES (1,8)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (2,7)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (4,4)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (5,1)

INSERT INTO #C VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (4,15)
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (5,2)


SELECT ID, MAX(tickvalue)
FROM
(SELECT C.ID, A.tickvalue t1, B.tickvalue t2, C.tickvalue t3
FROM #A AS a
JOIN #B AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
JOIN #C AS c ON b.ID = c.ID) p
UNPIVOT (tickvalue FOR tsource IN (t1,t2,t3)) AS unpvt
GROUP BY ID

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
DROP TABLE #C
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has got [Greatest](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php) function that does the same thing. Some times back I wrote an equivalent of the same in Sql Server which is available [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/80/posts/10694/day-16-greatest-and-least-function-in-oracle.aspx). Have a look and I think that will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative of use UNPIVOTE

```
SELECT c.ID,
       CASE WHEN a.tickvalue >= b.tickvalue THEN
                                                 CASE WHEN a.tickvalue >= c.tickvalue THEN a.tickvalue ELSE c.tickvalue END
                                            ELSE CASE WHEN b.tickvalue >= c.tickvalue THEN b.tickvalue ELSE c.tickvalue END END
FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.ID = b.ID
         JOIN C c ON b.ID = c.ID
```